# Swift remove array brackets and double quotes

Tags: swift

In my scenario, I have array of string value, I need to remove array bracket and double quotes like below, how to achieve this?

**I tried below code**

```
let selectedTeamMemberID = membersData.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.userid}
let intArray = selectedTeamMemberID.map { Int($0 ?? "")!}
print("\(intArray)")
```

**Expected output**

```
["1","2","3"] change to 1,2,3
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert your array into a comma-separated string? ("1,2,3")

Comment: @ParthBhuva I want to convert `["1","2"]` to `1,2`.

Comment: but you want your output as a string right?

Comment: @ParthBhuva No. I need just int value with comma seperator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to include objects without a userId you can filter on that property as well and force unwrap it. This avoids "empty" elements in the result

```
let selected = membersData.filter{$0.isSelected && $0.userid != nil}.map {$0.userid!}.joined(separator: ",")
```

But maybe more efficient and a cleaner solution is to use `compactMap` that maps and also filters out nil values

```
let selected = membersData.filter{$0.isSelected}.compactMap {$0.userid}.joined(separator: ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

You can Join an array of string with inbuilt method joined

```
let selectedTeamMemberID = membersData.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.userid}
let output = selectedTeamMemberID.joined(separator: ",")
```

Comment: I am getting error `Referencing instance method 'joined(separator:)' on 'BidirectionalCollection' requires the types 'String?' and 'String' be equivalent` at `selectedTeamMemberID.joined(separator: ",")`

Comment: what is the type of selectedTeamMemberID variable?

Answer (score 0):

As you are printing the array , it prints the string representation.

You need to iterate over the array and print the contents

```
intArray.forEach{print($0, terminator: ",")}
```

Comment: Can I achieve my result in a single line?

Comment: Yes, this would give you result in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

We can add Joined after data mapping

```
let selectedID = membersData.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{($0.userid ?? "")}.joined(separator: ",") // ["1","2","3"] to 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
selectedTeamMemberID.joined(separator: ",")
```

:)